# How to print different items in an array with a while loop

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop

I am creating a lotto number generator, with the powerball number at index zero in my array. however I am supposed to print all items in the array with the powerball nuber printing last. If it didn't have to print last I could easily do this with a foreach loop, but I'm stuck on how to do it otherwise.
anyone with any thoughts or ideas.

```
    {
        int[] Lotto = new int[6];
        int check = 0;
        //powerball 
        Random rand = new Random();
        check = rand.Next(5, 64);
        Lotto[0] = check;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < Lotto.Length;)
        {
            check = rand.Next(1, 64);
            Lotto[i] = check;
            i++;               
        }
        return Lotto;
    }
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can not put the powerball number at the end (index 5) instead of the first (index 0)?

Comment: its part of the exercise. I have to have powerball at index zero and print it last.

Comment: Then... when you print… use the same type loop you have now… starting at 1 and ending at 5… with each iteration output/print the value… then after the loop output/print the value at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, to print the first index last, something like…

```
for (int i = 1; i < Lotto.Length; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(Lotto[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine("PowerBall: " + Lotto[0]);
```

Or … If order does not matter, then simply loop through the array from the bottom up. Something like…

```
for (int i = Lotto.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  Console.WriteLine(Lotto[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if **into** for:

```
{
        int[] Lotto = new int[6];
        int check = 0;
        //powerball 
        Random rand = new Random();
        check = rand.Next(5, 64);
        Lotto[0] = check;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < Lotto.Length; i++)
        {
            check = rand.Next(1, 64);
            Lotto[i] = check;
            if(Lotto[0] >= 5 ){
              Console.WriteLine("The item is "+ Lotto);
            }else if(Lotto[0] >= 50 && Lotto[0] <=64){
              Console.WriteLine("The item is "+ Lotto);
            }
        }
        //return Lotto;
    }
```